# change value of one column with condition from another column

Tags: text-processing

I have a series of .txt files with 6 columns like this :

```
-44.2584 0.2603  42.7879 6 0.1 Precentral_L
49.3816  5.3947  40.4102 6 0.1 Precentral_R
-22.5897 9.5277  54.8691 6 0.1 Frontal-Sup_L
26.0365  32.0674 36.7889 6 0.1 Frontal-Sup_R
```

Number of rows are variable between files. I want to change the 4th column (6) with condition : when label is "R", change to 1. Is there a simple command for this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '$6 ~ /_R$/ { $4 = 1 }1' input.txt 
-44.2584 0.2603  42.7879 6 0.1 Precentral_L
49.3816 5.3947 40.4102 1 0.1 Precentral_R
-22.5897 9.5277  54.8691 6 0.1 Frontal-Sup_L
26.0365 32.0674 36.7889 1 0.1 Frontal-Sup_R
```

When column 6 ends in `_R`, change column $4 to `1`.  The `1` at the end of the awk script evaluates to true, so causes awk to execute its default action, which is `print`.

If you need to edit the input files rather than just print the results to stdout, and if you are using GNU's version of awk, you can use gawk's `inplace` library.  e.g.

```
awk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '$6 ~ /_R$/ { $4 = 1 }1' ./*.txt
```

Without GNU awk, you'd have to write the output for each input file to a temporary file and then rename it over the original.  Or just write the output files to a different directory and keep both the original and modified files (IMO it's generally a bad idea to overwrite your original copies of files unless you are extremely short of disk space.  You can always delete the original files later, but you can't undelete them unless you have a backup or snapshot).  e.g.

```
$ mkdir out

$ awk -v OUTDIR=./out '
    function basename(f) { sub(".*/", "", f); return f }
    $6 ~ /_R$/ { $4 = 1 }
    { print > OUTDIR "/" basename(FILENAME) }' ./*.txt

$ cat out/input.txt 
-44.2584 0.2603  42.7879 6 0.1 Precentral_L
49.3816 5.3947 40.4102 1 0.1 Precentral_R
-22.5897 9.5277  54.8691 6 0.1 Frontal-Sup_L
26.0365 32.0674 36.7889 1 0.1 Frontal-Sup_R
```

`FILENAME` is a built-in awk variable containing the name of the current file being processed.  awk doesn't have a built-in `basename()` function, so I had to write a simple one that just strips the path from a filename using awk's `sub()` function.  Redirection works in awk similarly to how it works in shell.

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/.*_R/s/\(\([^ ]* *\)\{3\}\)[0-9]/\11/' input_file
-44.2584 0.2603  42.7879 6 0.1 Precentral_L
49.3816  5.3947  40.4102 1 0.1 Precentral_R
-22.5897 9.5277  54.8691 6 0.1 Frontal-Sup_L
26.0365  32.0674 36.7889 1 0.1 Frontal-Sup_R
```

Comment: `\+` is not portable, I think. Use `\{1,\}` instead or, in this case a `*` will give the same results. Or you use ERE, giving even better readable code: `sed '/_R$/s/(([^ ]* +){3})[0-9]*/\11/'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/R$/{$4=1}1' file
-44.2584 0.2603  42.7879 6 0.1 Precentral_L
49.3816 5.3947 40.4102 1 0.1 Precentral_R
-22.5897 9.5277  54.8691 6 0.1 Frontal-Sup_L
26.0365 32.0674 36.7889 1 0.1 Frontal-Sup_R
```

```
$ awk '/R$/{$4=1}1' file | column -t
-44.2584  0.2603   42.7879  6  0.1  Precentral_L
49.3816   5.3947   40.4102  1  0.1  Precentral_R
-22.5897  9.5277   54.8691  6  0.1  Frontal-Sup_L
26.0365   32.0674  36.7889  1  0.1  Frontal-Sup_R
```

```
$ awk '/R$/{$4=1}1' file | column -o' ' -t
-44.2584 0.2603  42.7879 6 0.1 Precentral_L
49.3816  5.3947  40.4102 1 0.1 Precentral_R
-22.5897 9.5277  54.8691 6 0.1 Frontal-Sup_L
26.0365  32.0674 36.7889 1 0.1 Frontal-Sup_R
```